# System.Web.ModelBinding.IValueProvider vs System.Web.Mvc.IValueProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

What is the difference between `System.Web.ModelBinding.IValueProvider` and `System.Web.Mvc.IValueProvider`?
When would you use one instead of the other?
From MSDN, all I can see is that one applies to the .NET Framework and the other applies to ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: They are both identical (both define 2 methods - `bool ContainsPrefix(string prefix);` and `ValueProviderResult GetValue(string key);` - refer source code [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Web/ModelBinding/IValueProvider.cs) and [here](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/IValueProvider.cs)

Comment: Why the duplication?

Comment: No idea. Perhaps when it was being designed they might have had some other methods or properties in mind to use with the `DefaultModelBinder`, so created a new interface.